# Is there any way to get WSDL in use by SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL accessible through http. Then I create SoapClient in my PHP script

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/service.wsdl");
```

As part of this call SoapClient downloads WSDL file (or reuses it from cache). Is there any way to get a copy of this WSDL apart from re-downloading it from the source? Re-downloading is not really what I need as WSDL may differ from cached version. I really need to get a copy of WSDL (in XML form) currently in use by SoapClient.